# How to get SVG of Material Icons in OUTLINE style?

Tags: google-material-icons

I would like to get all .svg files with material icons  in OUTLINE style: https://material.io/tools/icons/?style=outline

I couldn't find it in repo on github. Is there any solution? I can download each icon manually from the link above but that's nonsense.

Thanks!

Comment: hello, I'm facing the same problem, have you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

[The official repository](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons?files=1) seems to have a lot of icons in different formats. Maybe you can collect what you want with some path pattern matching. Hopefully it won't be too many and become more tedious than manually downloading from the link.